# Bijection from Primes to Even Numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Is this statement true or false:

> There is a bijection from the prime numbers to the even numbers.

Please give a proof. Thanks in advance!

Comment: both are infinite countable, so bijective

Comment: @janmarqz Yeah I guess I want to find the bijection, more than finding its existence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p_i$ be the $i^{th}$ prime, then the mapping
$$
f(p_i)=2i
$$
is the the bijection you want.

The proof of bijectivity should be obvious.

examples:
$$f(2)=2\\
f(3)=4\\
f(5)=6\\
f(7)=8\\
f(11)=10\\
\vdots
$$

Comment: You missed "half" of the even numbers though!

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: $-2,-4,-6\ldots$

Comment: It depends on what they mean by "numbers" @AJ it is entirely plausible that they intend to have the natural numbers as the point of focus.  In the same light, you could argue that he missed "half of the primes" as well, since technically $-3, -5, -7, -11,\dots$ are primes as well.  Its just a matter of semantics, and easily fixed if you truly wanted to hit all even *integers* instead of merely hitting all even natural numbers (disregarding whether one counts zero as natural).

Comment: @AJStas it hadn't occur to me that he included the negative numbers as well. If that's the case then I could argue that $-2,-3,-5,...$ are my $-1^{th},-2^{nd},-3^{rd},...$ prime and get the bijection anyway.

Comment: The standard definition of a prime number is a number with no divisors other than $1$ and itself. An even number is defined to be a number of the form $n=2k$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. I don't really see any confusion. @JMoravitz

Comment: @AJStas The standard definition of a prime *natural number* is a whole number greater than one with no *positive divisors* other than $1$ and itself.  In general, however, they can vary by a unit (which in the integers are the numbers $\pm 1$).  You are working with the watered down definition and have forgotten some seemingly minor/unimportant words but words that are still technically necessary for the full definition.  See [prime ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal) and [prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) at wikipedia.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Sorry my math is bad, but why is this bijection surjective? How do you map onto 12?

Comment: I'll edit my post to add some examples.